# Jquery take single element form an HTMLElement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a var that returns an HTMLElement like this:

```
<li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-tabs-selected ui-state-active">
    <a href="#tabs-1">Tab 1</a>
    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-close tabby">Remove Tab</span>
</li>
```

From this I want to take the value of the href in the `a` element.

I know I can take href value using .attr() but how can I "select" the `a` before?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming var `that` as an HTMLElement as you have mentioned in the question you can try this

```
$(that).find('a').attr('href');
```

Comment: some alternatives that would work in this case also 1.) `$(that).children('a').attr('href');` (children will look a single level down the DOM tree where as `.find` will find any descendant(s)) or 2.) `$('a', that).attr('href')` (setting `that` as a context to select `a` elements from)